# How to let NVDA read Swing / GUI elements

Tags: java, swing, accessibility, nvda

I am using the Eclipse ide for Java development. When I execute the following code, the NVDA only reads ‘This is a frame’. It doesn’t read the button.

import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.accessibility.*;

```
public class MyButton {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame ("This is a frame");
JButton b = new JButton ("This one is a button");
    b.setBounds(50,100,95,30);
//f.add(b);
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setVisible(true);
b.setToolTipText("This tooltip makes the button accessible");;
}
}
```

**I have enabled AccessBridge via Ease of Access Center. I’m using Eclipse and NVDA on Windows 10.

Comment: Why would you comment out the add(...) statement? The button won't magically appear. Also, using a null layout will cause you problems. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it should work. You can try the following things:

- Make sure the access bridge is enabled
- restart NVDA and your app, or even reboot, after having installed and enabled access bridge
- If you are on a 64 bit system, try both 32 and 64 bit JVM. Only one of the two may work.
- Make sure that the focus indeed goes to the button and don't stay on the framm. The focus can be in an half-dead position where you can't read anyhting and where tab does nothing.
- Java 8: check that `jre\lib\accessibility.properties` contains a line like `assistive_technologies=com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge`. I don't know if something similar still exists for Java 11+.

Note that Swing and access bridge are old and kind of deprecated. For newer projects, you should use another GUI library.
To make accessible GUI, you can for example use SWT instead.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a long list of issues, I ended up switching to Eclipse for Java EE. I also updated my NVDA at around the same time. According to the What's New section of the update, they've done some improvements on Java AccessBridge.
I'm not sure if it was the NVDA update or switching to Java EE, but everything is working as it should.